# Possition a Custom Post Type Tab under Settings

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, options

So i would like to ask if there is any supported Wordpress way of positioning the CPT menu tab under the settings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So when creating the CPT you just change this in the arguments:

```
`show_in_menu
(boolean or string) (optional) Where to show the post type in the admin menu. show_ui must be true.

    Default: value of show_ui argument `
```

Link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type